# batch - How to stop confirmation of deletion of file in batch

Tags: batch-file

So, I have been working on html for a while but decided to go back to batch.
I decided to download
my "MS-DOS Parody" on another computer, and I noticed something while creating a new profile.
 I had to confirm that I wanted to delete a file (A file necessary for installation). I could figure this would be somewhat confusing, so I want it to delete with no confirmation. The download is here, and here is a snipet of my code also:

```
:reg
cls
set /p user=Enter your desired username: 
if %user% == todd goto exit
if %user% == Todd goto exit
if %user% == micheal goto exit
if %user% == Micheal goto exit
set /p pass=Enter your desired password: 
md "C:\XeonDOS\users\%user%"
md "C:\XeonDOS\users\%user%\login"
md "C:\XeonDOS\users\%user%\clr"
echo %pass% >> C:\XeonDOS\users\%user%\login\%user%.txt
echo 07 >> C:\XeonDOS\users\%user%\clr\%user%.txt
echo Type "Y". You know you want to.
rd /s C:\XeonDOS\users\Default
if not exist C:\XeonDOS\users\Default goto loginmenu1
```

If someone could help, that would be great. 
Edit: Also, for anyone wondering about the Zeos Inc. thing at the beginning, i created this about 2 years ago and was simply coming up with names for this was a school project. I will remove that in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not show a deletion of a file. You do show a deletion of a directory.

Generally, adding

```
>nul
```

to a command will suppress messages generated by the command

```
2>nul
```

to a command will suppress error messages generated by the command

and to automatically enter a `y`, you can use

```
echo y|your_command
```

Although for your case, you may wish to examine the documentation, which may reveal other options.

Again, in general from the prompt,

```
commandname /?
```

will show (sometimes terse) documentation.

```
commandname /?|more
```

will allow you to read that documentation line-by-line or screen-by-screen.

or

```
commandname /? >filename
```

will put that help into a file named `filename` for you to read with whatever editor or even word-processor takes your fancy.

eg.

```
rd /?
```

will show documentation for `rd` (remove directory)

```
del /?
```

ditto for `del` (delete file = *erase* file)

Comment: Alright thanks, I didn't know much about ">nul" and thought it was only for a couple of commands like "pause". But i can see it working on other commands too.